# Don't See Back Button in createStackNavigator React Native

Tags: react-native

I set up the `createStackNavigator` as follows:

```
export default function TabOneScreen() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true} >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1">
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

There is a button on `Screen1` that navigates to `Screen2`:

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2')}
```

However, when this navigates, **I don't see the button to go back** to `Screen1`. How do I enable this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you navigate to another page, you don't push another on top of the stack.

To do that you need to use

```
onPress={() => navigation.push('Screen2')}
```

**EDIT**

With a stack in a stack, you can try to pass parent navigation to props like

```
export default function TabOneScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true} >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1">
        <Stack.Screen parentNavigation={navigation} name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Then

```
this.props.parentNavigation.push('Screen2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this didn't work. I think it is because I have a StackNavigator inside a StackNavigator. The header is for the parent StackNavigator but I want to add the back button for the child StackNavigator. Could this cause the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I found this:

```
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/
```

Add this prop to your parent stack navigator: `headerShown: false`